# I am trying to sorting based on Text - XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to sorting on text based first text should be upper case then other start with first letter caps or small letter.
**Input XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
        <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">B</named-content></p>
        <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">BTS, USA, Inc. v Executive Perspectives, LLC (Conn. Super, Oct. 16, 2014, No. X10CV116010685) 2014 Conn Super Lexis 2644, aff’d (Conn App 2016) 142 A3d 342:</named-content></p>
        <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">buySAFE, Inc. v Google, Inc. (Fed Cir 2014) 765 F3d 1350:</named-content></p>
        <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Babcock v Butler County (3d Cir 2015) 806 F3d 153:</named-content></p>
        <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Buxbom v Smith (1944) 23 C2d 535:</named-content></p>
        <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Byrd v Roadway Express, Inc. (5th Cir 1982) 687 F2d 85:</named-content></p>
        <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">B.K.B. v Maui Police Dep’t (9th Cir 2002) 276 F3d 1091:</named-content></p>
    </root>
```

**Expected Output**

```
    <root>
    <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">B</named-content></p>
    <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">B.K.B. v Maui Police Dep’t (9th Cir 2002) 276 F3d 1091:</named-content></p>
    <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">BTS, USA, Inc. v Executive Perspectives, LLC (Conn. Super, Oct. 16, 2014, No. X10CV116010685) 2014 Conn Super Lexis 2644, aff’d (Conn App 2016) 142 A3d 342:</named-content></p>
    <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Babcock v Butler County (3d Cir 2015) 806 F3d 153:</named-content></p>
    <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Buxbom v Smith (1944) 23 C2d 535:</named-content></p>
    <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">buySAFE, Inc. v Google, Inc. (Fed Cir 2014) 765 F3d 1350:</named-content></p>
    <p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Byrd v Roadway Express, Inc. (5th Cir 1982) 687 F2d 85:</named-content></p>
    </root>
```

**My XSLT Code**

```
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="p[named-content[@content-type='emEntry'][matches(., '^([A-Za-z]+)')]]">
            <xsl:sort select="if(named-content[@content-type='emEntry' and matches(., '^([A-Z]+)')]) then named-content[@content-type='emEntry' and matches(., '^([A-Z]+)')] else upper-case(named-content[@content-type='emEntry'])" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Can any one help me that where is my wrong code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following meet your requirements? (Requirements were hard to understand. I assume there is more simple and faster XSLT code to accomplish this task ...)

It evaluates for the given input to the expected output https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4J7

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:key name="psStartingWithChar" match="p" use="upper-case(substring(translate(named-content/text(), translate(named-content/text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', ''), ''),1,1))"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:variable name="ctxt">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="temp">
            <xsl:for-each select="string-to-codepoints('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')">
                <xsl:variable name="ch" select="codepoints-to-string(.)"/>

                <xsl:variable name="root">
                    <xsl:for-each select="$ctxt">
                        <root>
                            <xsl:for-each select="key('psStartingWithChar',$ch)">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </root>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:variable>

                <xsl:for-each select="$root/root">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:for-each select="p[named-content[@content-type='emEntry'][string-length(.)=1 or matches(translate(., translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', ''), ''), '^([^a-z]{2,})')]]">
                            <xsl:sort data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
                            <xsl:copy>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                            </xsl:copy>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:for-each select="p[named-content[@content-type='emEntry'][not(string-length(.)=1 or matches(translate(., translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', ''), ''), '^([^a-z]{2,})'))]]">
                            <xsl:sort data-type="text" case-order= "upper-first" order="ascending"/>
                            <xsl:copy>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
                            </xsl:copy>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <root>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$temp/root/*"/>
        </root>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sir, Thanks for given me Solution :).

Comment: *"I assume there is more simple and faster XSLT code to accomplish this task"* I am convinced that is so. However, your answer suffers from the problem that plagues the question: it does not state the logic that is being implemented. Thus its usefulness is limited to those that would be willing to wade through it.

Comment: My approach only follows my view on the problem: 1.) clustering the result by alphabet (Latin) 2.) each cluster has two groups - each one with its own type of sorting: the first one holds all abbreviations, words starting with two upper case letters etc., and the second one holds all relatively conventionally formed names. This seems not too absurd to me. Certainly, the better the definition of „abbreviation“ and „normal names“  the better the algorithm and with less surprising results.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I get your question, is this what you are trying to do :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="p">
              <xsl:sort select="named-content"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEzknsV

Comment: Thanks for the reply but your code not given my Expected output. "buySAFE" this type text is not come proper sequence.

Comment: What is your expected sequence? What's the rule? From your example I can't see what you want you sort to be based on.

Comment: Sir, First Sorting start-with Caps letters after other Example sorting sequence: first comes should be start text with all caps after sequence other example "buySAFE" should be comes in between "Buxbom v Smith" to "Byrd v Roadway Express".

Comment: Ok sorry I can't help, I don't get what you're trying to do... Doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score -1):

To sort upper-case letters before lower-case letters, use the  `case-order` attribute of `xsl:sort`.

Here's a simplified example:

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="p">
            <xsl:sort select="named-content" data-type="text" order="ascending" case-order= "upper-first"/>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <p>B.K.B. v Maui Police Dep’t (9th Cir 2002) 276 F3d 1091:</p>
  <p>BTS, USA, Inc. v Executive Perspectives, LLC (Conn. Super, Oct. 16, 2014, No. X10CV116010685) 2014 Conn Super Lexis 2644, aff’d (Conn App 2016) 142 A3d 342:</p>
  <p>Babcock v Butler County (3d Cir 2015) 806 F3d 153:</p>
  <p>Buxbom v Smith (1944) 23 C2d 535:</p>
  <p>Byrd v Roadway Express, Inc. (5th Cir 1982) 687 F2d 85:</p>
  <p>buySAFE, Inc. v Google, Inc. (Fed Cir 2014) 765 F3d 1350:</p>
</root>
```

---

### Added:

I too do not understand what logic you want to implement to get the output you show.

I am able to get the same output by sorting the nodes in the following order:

- nodes that begin with initials come first;
- then sort alphabetically, ignoring case.

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="p">
            <xsl:sort select="number(matches(named-content, '^[A-Z](\.|[A-Z]|$)'))" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="named-content" data-type="text" order="ascending" lang="en"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9GPfN

```
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: From his comments on my answer, this does not seem to be what he wants to accomplish, but I don't understand what the ordering needs to be.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sir, Thanks for the reply if we have use `case-order= "upper-first` then this text 'buySAFE' position is comes good but upper letters position change can you check please my above expected output. your code output result: [link](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEzknsV/1)

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sir, I have attached PNG file please check.

Comment: @Sandy I am afraid this is still not clear. I have made a guess and added code based on this guess (see above). If this is not what you want, then I don't know.

Comment: @ michael.hor257k Sir, Thanks for given me times and good try I appreciated you sir but If I have add this Input XML another alphabetically order like (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, ... Z) then fail this code.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sir, Please Check (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9GPfN/1)

Comment: It doesn't fail. It follows the logic I stated in my reply: initials (even single-letter initials) come first.. If you want a different logic, you need to state it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't intend to spend any more time on this.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, Sir I have another try but not come proper sequence I am facing problem when start the text small letter. Can you please given me some solution?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sir, I have Solved the problem I am used in `xsl:sort` in `<xsl:sort select="if(named-content[@content-type='emEntry' and matches(., '^([A-Z]+)')]) then named-content[@content-type='emEntry' and matches(., '^([A-Z]+)')] else if(named-content[@content-type='emEntry' and matches(., '^([a-z])')]) then concat(upper-case(substring(.,1,1)), lower-case(substring(., 2))) else named-content[@content-type='emEntry']" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>`.