# How to Sorting Case Sensitive text - XSLT

Tags: sorting, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to sorting case sensitive text. If I am ruining my code then some output is ok but some case not proper given output my Code.
**Input XML**

```
<boxed-text content-type="casesBlock">
<p content-type="emCase" specific-use="02"><named-content content-type="emEntry">02 Micro Int’l, Ltd. v Monolithic Power Sys., Inc. (ND Cal 2006) 420 F Supp 2d 1070:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emLetHead">A</p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">AT&amp;T Mobility LLC v Concepcion (2011) 563 US 333, 131 S Ct 1740:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">ATPAC, Inc. v Aptitude Solutions, Inc. (ED Cal, Apr. 29, 2010, No. CIV. 2:10–294 WBS KJM) 2010 US Dist Lexis 42109:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">ATS Prods., Inc. v Champion Fiberglass, Inc. (ND Cal, Jan. 15, 2015, No. 13–cv–02403–SI) 2015 US Dist Lexis 5106:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">ATS Prods., Inc. v Champion Fiberglass, Inc. (ND Cal, Nov. 19, 2013, No. C 13-02403 SI) 2013 US Dist Lexis 13886:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Abel v Southern Shuttle Servs., Inc. (11th Cir 2011) 631 F3d 1210:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emLetHead">B</p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">BTS, USA, Inc. v Executive Perspectives, LLC (Conn. Super, Oct. 16, 2014, No. X10CV116010685) 2014 Conn Super Lexis 2644, aff’d (Conn App 2016) 142 A3d 342:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">buySAFE, Inc. v Google, Inc. (Fed Cir 2014) 765 F3d 1350:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Babcock v Butler County (3d Cir 2015) 806 F3d 153:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Buxbom v Smith (1944) 23 C2d 535:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Byrd v Roadway Express, Inc. (5th Cir 1982) 687 F2d 85:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emLetHead">E</p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">E*Healthline.com, Inc. v Pharmaniaga Behard (ED Cal, Oct. 23, 2018, No. 2:18-cv-01069-MCE-FB) 2018 US Dist Lexis 182041:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">E-Smart Technols., Inc. v Drizin (ND Cal, Jan. 6, 2009, No. C 06–05528) 2009 US Dist Lexis 272:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">eOnline v Chicago Consulting Partners (ND Ill, Mar. 29, 2002, No. 01 C 1918) 2002 US Dist Lexis 5464:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Entertainment Research Group, Inc. v Genesis Creative Group, Inc. (9th Cir 1997) 122 F3d 1211:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Epic Communications, Inc. v Richwave Technol., Inc. (2009) 179 CA4th 314:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emLetHead">H</p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">H.Q. Milton, Inc. v Webster (ND Cal, Nov. 22, 2017, No. 17-cv-06598-PJH) 2017 US Dist Lexis 193646:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">hiQ Labs, Inc. v LinkedIn Corp. (ND Cal, Aug. 14, 2017, No 17-cv-03301-EMC) 2017 US Dist Lexis 129088:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">HP Debt Exch. LLC v Wells Fargo Bank, N.A. (ND Cal, Feb. 12, 2014, No. C–13–04717 EDL) 2014 US Dist Lexis 18076:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Hinojosa v WCAB (1972) 8 C3d 150:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Hirt v Equitable Retirement Plan for Employees, Managers &amp; Agents (2d Cir 2008) 533 F3d 102:</named-content></p>
</boxed-text>
```

**I have written some code**: I have used for-each-group with group-adjacent below my code.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:output method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="boxed-text[@content-type='casesBlock']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-adjacent="not(matches(., '^([^a-z]{3,})'))">
            <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:sort select="lower-case(.)"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<boxed-text content-type="casesBlock">
<p content-type="emCase" specific-use="02"><named-content content-type="emEntry">02 Micro Int’l, Ltd. v Monolithic Power Sys., Inc. (ND Cal 2006) 420 F Supp 2d 1070:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emLetHead">A</p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">AT&amp;T Mobility LLC v Concepcion (2011) 563 US 333, 131 S Ct 1740:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">ATS Prods., Inc. v Champion Fiberglass, Inc. (ND Cal, Jan. 15, 2015, No. 13–cv–02403–SI) 2015 US Dist Lexis 5106:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">ATS Prods., Inc. v Champion Fiberglass, Inc. (ND Cal, Nov. 19, 2013, No. C 13-02403 SI) 2013 US Dist Lexis 13886:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">ATPAC, Inc. v Aptitude Solutions, Inc. (ED Cal, Apr. 29, 2010, No. CIV. 2:10–294 WBS KJM) 2010 US Dist Lexis 42109:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Abel v Southern Shuttle Servs., Inc. (11th Cir 2011) 631 F3d 1210:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emLetHead">B</p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">BTS, USA, Inc. v Executive Perspectives, LLC (Conn. Super, Oct. 16, 2014, No. X10CV116010685) 2014 Conn Super Lexis 2644, aff’d (Conn App 2016) 142 A3d 342:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Babcock v Butler County (3d Cir 2015) 806 F3d 153:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Buxbom v Smith (1944) 23 C2d 535:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">buySAFE, Inc. v Google, Inc. (Fed Cir 2014) 765 F3d 1350:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Byrd v Roadway Express, Inc. (5th Cir 1982) 687 F2d 85:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emLetHead">E</p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">E*Healthline.com, Inc. v Pharmaniaga Behard (ED Cal, Oct. 23, 2018, No. 2:18-cv-01069-MCE-FB) 2018 US Dist Lexis 182041:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">E-Smart Technols., Inc. v Drizin (ND Cal, Jan. 6, 2009, No. C 06–05528) 2009 US Dist Lexis 272:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Entertainment Research Group, Inc. v Genesis Creative Group, Inc. (9th Cir 1997) 122 F3d 1211:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">eOnline v Chicago Consulting Partners (ND Ill, Mar. 29, 2002, No. 01 C 1918) 2002 US Dist Lexis 5464:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Epic Communications, Inc. v Richwave Technol., Inc. (2009) 179 CA4th 314:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emLetHead">H</p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">H.Q. Milton, Inc. v Webster (ND Cal, Nov. 22, 2017, No. 17-cv-06598-PJH) 2017 US Dist Lexis 193646:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">HP Debt Exch. LLC v Wells Fargo Bank, N.A. (ND Cal, Feb. 12, 2014, No. C–13–04717 EDL) 2014 US Dist Lexis 18076:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Hinojosa v WCAB (1972) 8 C3d 150:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">hiQ Labs, Inc. v LinkedIn Corp. (ND Cal, Aug. 14, 2017, No 17-cv-03301-EMC) 2017 US Dist Lexis 129088:</named-content></p>
<p content-type="emCase"><named-content content-type="emEntry">Hirt v Equitable Retirement Plan for Employees, Managers &amp; Agents (2d Cir 2008) 533 F3d 102:</named-content></p>
</boxed-text>
```

**With PNG File for Example:**
[image]

My Code not proper work can any one help me please.

Comment: Your question talks about case sensitive text but then in your `xsl:sort` you use `lower-case(.)`. That doesn't seem to make sense. So try to explain in a bit more detail which grouping and sorting criteria you want to implement.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sir, I want to move below the text that is starting with the small letter in my file when it's come after starting text All caps. Moving text Example ("buySAFE, eOnline, hiQ, ...."). Please find above I have added Expected Output file with PNG. please check PNG file first point if is it move?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of your previous question (and just as unclear): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61524656/i-am-trying-to-sorting-based-on-text-xslt

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sir, Please check previews Question my comment I have explain please check output https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9GPfN/1

Comment: I don't think it will help us understand your problem if you link to an online sample with an even more complex data sample.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sir, All sorting is good but I am facing the problem where comes text start with Exmple `buySAFE`  sort order between `Buxbom v Smith` and `Byrd v Roadway` Is it possible?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sir, if is not any Solution my Question then you can see my comment in first XSLT while given me sorting output some case not proper sorting start with small letter then we can write another XSLT with write the program move element  `xsl:for-each-group select="p"` with `group-adjacent`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Sir, I have Solved the problem I am used in `xsl:sort` in `<xsl:sort select="if(named-content[@content-type='emEntry' and matches(., '^([A-Z]+)')]) then named-content[@content-type='emEntry' and matches(., '^([A-Z]+)')] else if(named-content[@content-type='emEntry' and matches(., '^([a-z])')]) then concat(upper-case(substring(.,1,1)), lower-case(substring(., 2))) else named-content[@content-type='emEntry']" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

You are only sorting within a group of adjacent entries, and your grouping criteria are such that "buySafe" is going to be in a group of its own. Sorting a group containing a single item obviously has no effect.

I can't see what you are trying to achieve by doing the grouping.

Comment: Sir, I have revived not sorting XML, after that I have sorting text first sorting start with number after that sorting Alphabetically order For Example like start-with (01, 02, A, A.A.A, ABCD, Aman, aNan, Aoan, B, B.B.B, BBCS, Bman, bNan, Boan, ...). I want only one XSLT create when given me proper output.